# how to curry a method with one parameter

Tags: ruby

here is my code:

```
def f x
  x
end

g = method(:f).to_proc.curry.(123)

p g
```

I want `g` to be a callable that takes no parameters and applies `123` to `f`. Instead, `g` contains the result of the application.

Am I doing it the complicated way?

EDIT: yes, `g = lambda {f 123}` works, but I am asking how to curry `f`.

Comment: Seems like this is the only way currying can work in ruby!
Try `g = method(:f).to_proc.curry[123]`, which also works.

Comment: Currently `method(:f).curry[123]` works fine. I don't know if this was the case in 2013, but you can leave away the _#to_proc_ call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for curry](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-curry) says that

> If a sufficient number of arguments are supplied, it passes the supplied arguments to the original proc and returns the result.

So in this case you haven't really curried your function from a theoretical point of view, but practically you have. The

```
g = lambda {f 123}
```

seems to be closer to the spirit of returning a function that you can then call to evaluate, at least once all the arguments are determined.

Comment: The "new" lambda one line syntax `g = -> { f 123 }`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to wrap your function `f` inside a `lambda` (evaluating f). Then you can curry the `lambda` expression, something like this:

```
g = lambda{f 123}.curry
p g[] // or g.call
```

Now `g` is callable that takes no parameters.

Comment: This doesn't really curry the parameter, as you still have to supply it when invoking the method.